# This problem concerns application of a residue theorem. I am not sure if I can apply the residue theorem. Need some pointers.

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

I am to evaluate the integral
$$
\int\limits^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\sinh(y)}{y^{2}-c^{2}}dy.
$$

What I am not sure is if I can apply the residue theorem. The function $\sinh(y)$ diverges at $y\!=\!\infty$. With a divergent integrand, how can I apply the residue theorem? The $\sinh(y)$ has an essential singularity at infinity.

Please let me know if I can apply the residue theorem even if the integrand diverges at infinity.

Comment: Please keep your contact information to yourself. Also, don't worry about the downvote: I take it that you have seen [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), and you clearly have shown some thinking of your own.

Comment: what does evaluate the integral mean exactly?

Comment: The integral diverges: the integrand doesn't go to zero for large $y$, and also there are non-integrable singularities at $y=\pm c$

Comment: The integral could have been evaluated by using the residue theorem. Residue theorem can be applied to hyperbolic functions too. The poles at $y\!=\!\pm{c}$ can be considered by using the residue theorem. The problem is with $\sinh(y)$ term - that diverges at $y\to\infty$.  Note that if instead of $\sinh(y)$ in the numerator we had the term $\tanh(y)$, I would have evaluated this integral exactlyt in a heartbeat. But this integrand does not converge. That's why I am asking for pointers.

Comment: If you know that the integral diverges, then what precisely is being asked here?